# How to find the optimal git concept for my style of working

Tags: git, directory-structure, code-organization

I'm currently cleaning my dev environment and looking for a good way to organize my code via git's concepts. For reasons too long to explain, the structure of my project looks like this:

- independent code file #0
- independent code file #1
- ...
- independent code file #N

They are all single (large) files, and I cannot move them into respective subfolders because the software loading them loads folder wise (non recursive), and managing like 30 subfolders that'd change all the time is insanely cumbersome. They are all independent from each other.
I tend to work on whatever file I feel like at the moment, so most of them are always in a state of mid-increment.

Here are my problems with each of the structures that git offers (that I know of):

1. **the entire folder as repo, branches for each file:** I'd have to switch branches 100 times a day and before/after results of a change are hard to compare. Branches would always be behind each other except in the file I updated. Cumbersome to merge.
2. **branches for each file, laid out as worktree:** the software loading them would still need to track lots of folders (cumbersome), and on top of that, show a lot of duplicates since each branch contains all the other files as well
3. **Each file as git submodule:** each file has its own git repo, again lots of subfolders.

Is there *any* proper way to track each file separately? I would be OK with copying each working increment to a separate repo - I do this right now, most of the files end up not working experiments anyways and are discarded. So I have two folders, one with atm 8 working increments and a folder with 30-ish random experiments. The folder with the working increments is a regular repo, so I have really spaced, gigantic commits.
I thought of having all git submodules in one folder and each gitignore ignoring everything but the file I work on, but that's probably *really* ugly and dumb. I feel there must be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: You cannot make a file as a git submodule — submodules are always subdirectories.

Comment: Well yes, I meant each file tracked via its own repo, and then all repos combined via one super repo overarching all the other repos as submodules. Which is not feasible for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: I think one of the easier solutions would be to create a git repository for each file in separate folders. Then, write a bash, powershell, or whatever you like script that will copy the files from those subfolders to the one folder that you are trying to backup.

Comment: Regarding, "The folder with the working increments is a regular repo, so I have really spaced, gigantic commits." Why do you have spaced, gigantic commits?

Answer (score 0):

[`rcs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/) is still perfectly good for single-file projects. Git's not good for those if they need to be in a directory with others of their kind, which is why the metastasized oneliners in my `bin` directory are tracked with rcs. Closest way I know with Git is to have a directory full of symlinks to the individual repo work tree files, yuck.